# Running Flask-SQLAlchemy query with Flask-APScheduler interval

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, apscheduler

For each month I running interval **Flask-SQLAclhemy** queries with **Flask-APScheduler**.

In my app I need to run queries to update the payment feature on my app automatically.

But also the possibility of rows can be 1000, even more's.
It is safe or bad to run **Flask-SQLAlchemy** queries 1000+ in a time, with **Flask-APScheduler** interval..?

Comment: You can run it if it's from an architectural point of view is a good idea is hard to answer with the given pieces of information. In general, you should make sure that `Flask-APSchedule` runs only once, so it doesn't start a new interval while the other one is still running. Further - if you dont have it in place yet - you should monitor the execution and also make sure that I one query fails the application executes the others and just keeps the failed ones.